# HttpRuntime.Cache across two request by different user at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scope, httpruntime.cache

I am bit confused here with caching so thought to ask for an expertise.

I have Inserted `HttpRuntime.Cache`

I have 2 users via 2 different login, working on the same caching at the same time i.e., one user is clearing it and another one accessing it.

I have written below code while accessing caching.

```
if (HttpRuntime.Cache[MyKey] == null)
 {
     
     HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(MyKey, CityCollection);
     
 }
 else
 {
     CityCollection = (List<CityDTO>)HttpRuntime.Cache[MyKey];        
 }
```

Will it give me an object reference for 2nd user? Or 2nd user will get collection form caching?

Or Does it work as per the request?

Comment: From the Cache docs: *One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it remains valid as long as the application domain remains active.* so all users will get and insert from the same Cache.

Comment: This might still throw a null ref exception though, because between the null check and the last line, the cache could have expired in that time.

Comment: @DavidG: what would be the best approach here?